# GTM - Filter out specific brands for purchase

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

What I am trying to accomplish using GTM is filtering out specific brands purchase data and send that information to them. So when a purchase happens and it has multiple brands, I want to send only the brands information (Product Name, Product Price, Product Qty) and not the entire basket of goods that get pushed through the datalayer. Is this achievable systematically? Or do I have to manually create different variables to capture the brand specific revenue, qty, etc and use that to push to the different brands?

Answer (score 1):

You would definitely have to make a CJS variable that would parse your items array in the EEC object, then return the filtered array. You would use this variable to set the `items` property of your EEC tag to effectively override the items array in DL.